# Weird Windows 7 issue

Tags: windows-7

One of our customers complained that out site is not loading fully. It turned out that in the response from the server all `<script>` tags and their contents were removed. We use javascript heavily. She is using Windows 7 and the site was working before.

She told the site stopped working after some Windows 7 updates. But nothing suspicious in the update history. The site is not working in all browsers like IE,FF and Chrome. But other sites were working and their scripts were loaded properly.

After spending lot of time trying various things I changed the protocol from http to https.(Don't ask me why). Then it started working!!!. I couldn't understand what the issue is. Is there some firewall or third-party software that strips the script tags (or in someway modify) the http response?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a case of having a proxy modify your page requests. I would suggest checking security software (i.e. Norton, McAfee, SiteAdvisor, that inject and remove stuff etc) to see if they are modifying pages or if a corporate intranet firewall is modifying, since HTTPS is encrypted end-to-end and cannot be modified.